# Check RDF file syntax using jena

Tags: syntax, sparql, rdf, apache-jena

I have a `.ttl` file that I have written. I am on mac environment. I was wondering how can I use apache jena to check if the file is valid. What terminal commands are needed to do this? I have downloaded the apache jena packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `riot` with `$PATH_TO_JENA/bin/riot --validate $PATH_TO_FILE`

```
riot [--time] [--check|--noCheck] [--sink] [--base=IRI] [--out=FORMAT] [--compress] file ...
  Parser control
      --sink                 Parse but throw away output
      --syntax=NAME          Set syntax (otherwise syntax guessed from file extension)
      --base=URI             Set the base URI (does not apply to N-triples and N-Quads)
      --check                Addition checking of RDF terms
      --strict               Run with in strict mode
      --validate             Same as --sink --check --strict
      --rdfs=file            Apply some RDFS inference using the vocabulary in the file
      --nocheck              Turn off checking of RDF terms
      --stop                 Stop parsing on encountering a bad RDF term
  Output control
      --output=FMT           Output in the given format, streaming if possible.
      --formatted=FMT        Output, using pretty printing (consumes memory)
      --stream=FMT           Output, using a streaming format
      --compress             Compress the output with gzip
  Time
      --time                 Time the operation
  Symbol definition
      --set                  Set a configuration symbol to a value
  General
      -v   --verbose         Verbose
      -q   --quiet           Run with minimal output
      --debug                Output information for debugging
      --help
      --version              Version information
```